# What kind of operator is the indefinite integral?

Tags: indefinite-integrals, differential-operators

The derivative operator $\frac{d}{dx}(f(x))$ is a map from function space to function space. So is the definite integral $\int_0^xf(x)dx$, which maps $f(x)$ to the function that gives the signed area between $f(x)$ and the $x$ axis, up to the value of $x$ that you put in.

However, $\int f(x)dx$ does not map to a specific function. An infinite amount of functions satisfy it, namely $C+\int_0^xf(x)dx$ for all $C\in \mathbb R$.

**So what kind of operator is $\int dx$ ?**
**Is it even an operator? What kind of object is it?**

**Edit**: Because I am not entirely sure what kind of object the indefinite integral is, I'm also somewhat unsure about the **exact** meaning of indefinite integral equations.

For example, based on the chain rule, we can derive: $$\frac{\delta f(g(x))}{\delta x}= g'(x)f'(g(x)) \implies \int\frac{\delta f}{\delta g(x)}(g(x))dg=\int\frac{\delta g}{\delta x}(x)\frac{\delta f}{\delta g}(g(x))dx$$

Comment: I don't think it's a formal notation.  You can undenstand it as there it means that if you take a primitive on the left hand side, then there exists a primitive on the left hand side that is equals to it.  The notation is not very clear elsewhere, what is $\delta f / \delta g$ when $g$ is a function ?

Answer (score 2):

Can be considered an operator with range in a quotient space.

If $C+\int_0^xf\in F$, with $F$ some function space that contains the constant functions, the real numbers can be considered a subspace of $F$ and $\int f(x)\,dx$ is a class of equivalence in the space $F/\Bbb R$.